# One confusion when creating linked list with list

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I am using below function to creating a linked list, head1, with the list, ll. It works very well. But I just confuse why using the commented part, the linked list cannot be created successfully, compared with its above three lines? What is the detailed reason?

```
def head_list_to_linkedlist(ll):
    head1 = ListNode(ll[0])
    for val in ll[1:]:
        node = ListNode(val)
        node.next = head1
        head1 = node
        #ListNode(val).next = head1
        #head1 = ListNode(val)
    return head1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commented code creates **two** nodes. The first one is lost because it is not captured with a name, while the second one has nothing to do with the first, so in the end it is no different from *only* doing `head1 = ListNode(val)`

If your purpose is to somehow shorten the code a bit, then take these actions:

- Make sure that the `ListNode` constructor can take an optional second argument which will be the value of the `next` attribute of the constructed node:

  ```
  class ListNode:
      def __init__(self, val nxt=None):
          self.val = val
          self.next = nxt
  ```
- Then, use that argument to *prefix* values to the linked list. To make sure you get them in the right order, iterate the `ll` list in reverse:

  ```
  def head_linkedlist_to_list(ll):
      head = None
      for val in reversed(ll):
          head = ListNode(val, head)  # the old head becomes the next reference
      return head
  ```

This has as additional advantage that it will also work when `ll` is empty.